# Changing SplitView Size does not respect ColumnLayout minimumWidth?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a horizontal `SplitView`, where the left part should be my application main screen and the right part an area for tool options. In the right area, I have a `SwipeView` which I want to control via a `TabBar`. The `SwipeView` and `TabBar` should always fill the right `SplitView` and have a minium size of 400. If I move the `SplitView` handle to the left and then to the right, beyond the 400 pixel minimum size, the resizing does not stop (actually the `SplitView` border is resting at 400) but the `TabBar` and the `SplitView` get resized to smaller sizes. Below you find the code to reproduce the behaviour. How would I need to do it, so the `TabBar` and `SplitView` do not change beyond the minimum size?

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    SplitView {
        id: splitView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Page {
            id: page
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Text {
                id: text1
                text: qsTr("Page")
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: 170
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }


            ColumnLayout {
                Layout.minimumWidth: 400
                Layout.preferredWidth: 400
                spacing: 0

                TabBar {
                    id: tabbar
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    currentIndex: view.currentIndex

                    TabButton {
                        text: qsTr("1")
                    }

                    TabButton {
                        text: qsTr("2")
                    }

                    TabButton {
                        text: qsTr("3")
                    }
                }

                SwipeView {
                    id: view
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    currentIndex: tabbar.currentIndex

                    Item {
                        id: tab0
                        Rectangle {
                            color: "red"
                        }
                    }


                    Item {
                        id: tab1
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent // -> This command is fill all screen so I don't click TabButtons.
                            color: "blue"
                        }
                    }


                    Item {
                        id: tab2
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            color: "lightblue"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite strange effect... I already worked with SplitView, but if I remember correctly, it behaved well for me in the past.

I played a bit with you example and it seems the `Layout.fillWidth` is what seems to cause issues. If it is okay for you, you could try to set a maximum width on the first item in the split view and bind it's width to the window width (minus the width for your side bar). Here's what I found working for me:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    SplitView {
        id: splitView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Page {
            id: page

            Layout.maximumWidth: window.width - 400
            width: window.width - 400

            Text {
                id: text1
                text: qsTr("Page")
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: 170
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }


        ColumnLayout {
            width: 400
            spacing: 0
            clip: true

            TabBar {
                id: tabbar
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                currentIndex: view.currentIndex

                TabButton {
                    text: qsTr("1")
                }

                TabButton {
                    text: qsTr("2")
                }

                TabButton {
                    text: qsTr("3")
                }
            }

            SwipeView {
                id: view
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                currentIndex: tabbar.currentIndex

                Item {
                    id: tab0
                    Rectangle {
                        color: "red"
                    }
                }


                Item {
                    id: tab1
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent // -> This command is fill all screen so I don't click TabButtons.
                        color: "blue"
                    }
                }


                Item {
                    id: tab2
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        color: "lightblue"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this is rather a workaround, but at least you should be able to get the desired effect you need.